# running multiple tasks at a time in r

Tags: r

```
rm(list=ls())

mat<-data.frame(matrix(NA,32,11))

mat[c(1,11,21),]<-mtcars[c(1,11,21),]

tasks <- list(

  job1 = function(){repeat{na<-which(is.na(mat1[,1]));mat1[na,]=mat1[na-1,];if(all(is.na(mat1[,1])==F)==T)break}mat1},

 job2 = function(){repeat{na<-which(is.na(mat2[,1]));mat2[na,]=mat2[na-1,];if(all(is.na(mat2[,1])==F)==T)break}mat2},

  job3 = function()repeat{na<-which(is.na(mat3[,1]));mat3[na,]=mat3[na-1,];if(all(is.na(mat3[,1])==F)==T)break}mat3},

  # To check that the computations are indeed running in parallel.

  job4 = function() for (i in 1:5) { cat("4"); Sys.sleep(1) },

  job5 = function() for (i in 1:5) { cat("5"); Sys.sleep(1) },

  job6 = function() for (i in 1:5) { cat("6"); Sys.sleep(1) }

)

mat<-data.frame(matrix(NA,32,11))

mat[c(1,11,16),]<-mtcars[c(1,11,21),]

mat1<-mat[1:10,]

mat2<-mat[11:15,]

mat3<-mat[16:32,]

cl <- makeCluster( length(tasks) )

clusterExport(cl, list("mat1","mat2","mat3"))     # make sure mtcars is loaded

out <- clusterApply( cl, tasks, function(f) f())

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: could you please, suggest syntax which is suitable for the above task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cl <- makeCluster( length(tasks) )
 clusterExport(cl, "mat")
 out <- clusterApply( cl, tasks,function(f) f())
```

You need to make objects available to the worker processes. This is done by `clusterExport`.

Furthermore, note that your functions are somewhat weird. The same task is completed in each of the worker processes, which is probably not what you intend them to do. Note that simply writing `mat[1:10]` just prints the corresponding output, nothing else. Try e.g. the following

```
   job1 = function() {
   mat <- mat[1:10, ];              # note the difference here
   repeat{ 
   na<-is.na(mat[,1]);
   mat[na,] <-mtcars[na,];
   if(all(is.na(mat[,1]))==F) break}
   }
```

Do a similar adjustment to the other jobs. And then call

```
 cl <- makeCluster( length(tasks) )
 clusterExport(cl, list("mat", "mtcars"))     # make sure mtcars is loaded
 out <- clusterApply( cl, tasks, function(f) f())
 stopCluster(cl)
```

This is still slightly inefficient since you are exporting the whole matrix to each worker process, and then only use a subset. But I guess the principle is understood.

Comment: If i run above lines,I am getting 6 empty lists.

Comment: From first job, I want to know where ever(In which record) I have NA values in mat[1:10,].I want to replace those records with another data set same records. Here both data set have same dimension.

Comment: Thanks  coffeinjunky. I resolved this task by your help. I dont know how to add my code here, that's why i edited my actual code.